# How to turn down a recruiter without burning the bridge?

Tags: interviewing, recruiting

I just started a new job, and I've received a few invitations to interview at other companies since beginning. I don't want to leave my job yet, as I'm just getting started and I really like it, but I don't want to close the door on some of these recruiters for future opportunities that may exist.

The first step in many of these job applications is an online assessment of coding ability, and the next step would be onsite.

In a year or two, I would like to have the option to reach out to the recruiters that reached out to me, and ask to start the process up again. How far along in the interviewing process must I go so that the recruiter would want to put me back into the pipeline?

Additionally, how far is too far? If I have little intention of accepting an offer, when should I pull out of the interview process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When recruiters call me, I answer:

> Thank you Mr/Mrs X for this opportunity.
>
> I am currently fulfilled by my current position as a **permanent**
>   **programmer**.
>
> If you are interested, send me a LinkedIn invitation then we can make
>   a follow up call in 6 months to update our respective position?
>
> Thanks again, Have a great day!

Replace permanent and programmer by your current job status and your current position.

Usually, the recruiter will send you a LinkedIn invite and he/she will schedule it in their system then the recruiter or one of his co-worker will call you back in 6 months. So they will do all the job to keep everything alive. You just have to answer cheerfully the calls.

Also, by having the recruiter adding you on LinkedIn, you will receive more invites from co-workers and ex-co-workers of the recruiter. So you will get more calls, more emails and more invites, indirectly more job offers, more choices.

Comment: This is exactly the advice I was looking for. Great ideas! I would upvote you if I had the reputation.

Answer (score 8):

Nate, don't worry about it.  In a year, 75% of those recruiters will have moved on to some other job where they actually make a buck.  Turnover rate with recruiters is extremely high.

The rest don't care that you've lost contact, because they've learned not to take things personally.  It's the only way they can survive in the business, so there's no need to preoccupy yourself as long as you've left off on a positive note at your last contact.  Politely turn down the offer, and say that you'll hope to speak again in the future.  It's that simple.

Comment: I guess I should be more clear. I would like to join the recruiter's company, just not now. What do I need to do so that I might still have the option in the future?

Comment: Your option is always going to be open as long as you're not rude.  Recruiters who can't get candidates don't keep their jobs, so unless you are a jerk, it's always in their interest to keep the door open for you.  Stop overthinking this :)

Answer (score 6):

"I don't want to leave my job yet, as I'm just getting started and I really like it"

Simply tell them this. Direct is good - they certainly wouldn't rather spend a bunch of time on screening activities/ interviews, and then have you turn around when there's an offer because you were never interested.
Say something like 'Timing isn't right - I want to get some runs on the board at the situation I just started. Thanks for considering me.'

Answer (score 1):

I've used several variants of

> I am not currently available.  Feel free to contact me again next year.

(And some of them even have!)

I would let them know the situation immediately, at first contact, before a skills assessment; they are unlikely to expend further time and effort on a candidate who is not available in a reasonable timeframe. (And in a year your skills and interests will have presumably progressed; you may not want to be on the record at a certain skill level that no longer represents you.)